# Join two lists in LINQ, writing into other list

Tags: c#, linq

I created a linq-select to join two lists.

```
var materialneu =
        (from material in ma
        join mb5b in mb
        on material.Mat_matwerk equals mb5b.Mb5b_matwerk
        into grouping
        from mb5b2 in grouping.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new {material, zugang = (mb5b2 == null ? string.Empty : mb5b2.Mb5b_zugang.ToString())}).ToList();
```

I get no error, but `zugang` is always empty if I go through `materialneu` ...
`mb5b` is definitely not empty, as well as the `Mb5b_zugang`.
Also I would prefer to fill a field in my material-list, which already exists(but it is not filled yet).
Is this possible?
like

```
select new {material, material.zugang = mb5b3.Mb5b_zugang}
```

?
It allways gives me an error if I try it like this.

Comment: what type is `material.Mat_matwerk` and `mb5b.Mb5b_matwerk`?

Comment: @Grundy Both are strings

Comment: are you sure that `grouping` not empty? can you provide sample value of `material.Mat_matwerk' and 'mb5b.Mb5b_matwerk`?

Comment: it seems like you don't have the same strings in `material` and `mb5b`

Comment: Fck, you are totally true. I dont see how i missed the fail at my splitting there, i think i was so concentrated on linq because i did it the first time that i was so sure this was the problem ... thanks! Still, does some1 know if it is possible to set material.zugang like in my last example ?

Comment: in your last sample is not valid syntax, but posibly you need use [let clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx)

Comment: also linq - language for selecting data, not for change existing data

Comment: thanks ;) Post i will delete my answer as far as everything is okay with the linq. thanks for your help, i will upvote sth from u somewhere else ;)

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will work: Add `Group`

```
var materialneu =
    (from material in ma
    Group join mb5b in mb
    on material.Mat_matwerk equals mb5b.Mb5b_matwerk
    into grouping        
    from mb5b2 in grouping.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {material, zugang = (mb5b2 == null ? string.Empty : mb5b2.Mb5b_zugang.ToString())}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i had a problem bevor the actual linq.

Comment: I didn't get you. You mean you had a problem before the linq?

Comment: Yes, the linq was correct, but mb5b.Mb5b_matwerk was filled wrong, so there could be no equal items :) My bad